# Using multi dimensional array in ant design table

Tags: arrays, reactjs, antd

I have a use case where i have to pass an array which contains multiple arrays inside

> Array :

```
       "mainArray": [
         {
         "id": "1",
         "count": 5,
         "strengthEdit": 1,
         "date": "2019-04-07",
         "lastDate": "2018-09-12",
         "array1": [
           {
            "id": "17",
            "innerrArray1": {
              "name": "A"
             },
            "availability": 20,
            "lastEditedCount": 5
            },
           {
            "id": "18",
            "innerrArray1": {
             "name": "B"
            },
          "availability": 5,
          "lastEditedCount": 5
           }
          ],
          "array2": [
           {
            "id": "2",
            "innerrArray2": {
              "name": "a"
             },
            "strength": 80,
            "lastEditedCount": 1
           },
           {
            "id": "3",
            "innerrArray2": {
              "name": "b"
            },
            "strength": 40,
            "lastEditedCount": 1
           }
         ]
       }
      ]
```

Passing this array into ant design's table as

```
<Table dataSource={mainArray} scroll={{ y: 350 }}>
```

I have resolved this by making another array and destructing the inner arrays into it but i am hoping to a get more cleaner approach towards this.

```
let consumeArr = [...mainArray.innerArray1,...mainArray.innerArray2]
```

and sending this to

```
<Table dataSource={consumeArr } scroll={{ y: 350 }}>
```

Is there any other possible way / official way i missed to implement

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://ant.design/components/table/#Table)
 `dataSource` accept only `any[]`, and there are no other ways to do it differently.

So the only solution is to modify the input data under the desired format.
But, perhaps, in this example inner arrays should be `array1` and `array2`?
You can use something like this, if the number of arrays is not static:

```
const extractArrays = (data) => {
    return Object.values(data).filter(obj => Array.isArray(obj)).flat(1)
}
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/n10dxzoy/

Comment: interesting! I knew dataSource only accepts array. but i wondering how will you display if my data contains for example : [1,[2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],9].

Comment: depends on the form in which this data should be presented, if each elements in this case must be row, you can use [1,[2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],9].flat(1) to concat to single array